# Assistance with a slow running CTE Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below query is being used to populate a Power BI report to determine what characteristics (the last six digits of the PARTNO field - `RIGHT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO,6)`) have been ran in the last 24 hours.

I believe the report has always ran poorly and, with enhancements to new characteristics being added and saved to the database, has made this even worse. I am not well versed enough in SQL Server to spot the bottleneck.

```
WITH FilterCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        i.ITEM_CODE,
        CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) as LineID,
        CONCAT(i.ITEM_CODE,RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) as LinkID,
        CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), i.ITEM_CODE, RIGHT(PARTNO,6)) as SpecID,
        CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), i.ITEM_CODE, RIGHT(PARTNO,6), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) as ControlLimitID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), 
                            RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) 
        ORDER BY MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 102)) DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM dbo.OC_VDATA   INNER JOIN
                            dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX ON dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX
                            AND dbo.OC_VDATA.DATETIME = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES i ON LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = i.SPEC_NO
                            AND LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = i.SPEC_NO 
                        INNER JOIN 
                            stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS p ON dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 = p.PLANT_CODE
    WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 101) > DATEADD(hour, - 24, GETDATE())) 
        AND (dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL28 LIKE 'PLASTIC%')
        AND RIGHT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO,6) in ('008400',
                                '008500',
                                '036150',
                                '043300',
                                '043400',
                                '043200',
                                '043202',
                                '008800',
                                '008810',
                                '009600'
                                    )
    GROUP BY i.ITEM_CODE, 
                CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)),
                CONCAT(i.ITEM_CODE,RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)),
                CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),i.ITEM_CODE,RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL5)),
                CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),i.ITEM_CODE,RIGHT(PARTNO,6)),
                CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1),i.ITEM_CODE,RIGHT(PARTNO,6),RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6))
)

SELECT * FROM FilterCTE
```

Here is the expected output:
[image]

Could someone assist me in knowing where the bottleneck is and how did you spot it?

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: `WHERE (CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40, 101)` has a smell to it; why are you storing date (and time) data as `varchar`? That clause isn't SARGable, but is very likely a contributor to reason why your query is performing poorly

Comment: Instead of `LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = i.SPEC_NO` can you not do `OC_VDATA.PARTNO LIKE i.SPEC_NO + '%'`? (Same for the other clause where you use `LEFT`.) Though if the left most 12 characters are a join criteria, why is that data not in its own column?

Comment: `RIGHT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 6)` is also not going to be SARGable in the `WHERE`. The more I look at it, the more i feel like the query is a small part of the problem; I suspect the *design* is the real problem here.

Comment: If you're using SSMS you can add the Execution Plan and that will give us some clues... I believe the culprit is around the substring in the join, but an execution plan attached to your question might give some clues to the folks who know how to read those things

Comment: @Larnu I've taken your advice and aliased the objects in the FROM clause like you suggested. And the data structure stinks, I agree. Working from a previous employee's implementation which is no longer here.

Comment: @Josh I am using SSMS...where do I get to the Execution Plan that you are suggesting?

Comment: @EricALionsFan if I remember correctly, Ctrl+M maybe?  Maybe you can find the button for it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16  I actually dont have SSMS installed anymore to find it